# How to prove this multivariable function is constant?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose the multivariable function $z=f(x,y)$ is defined on $\mathbb R^2$, has continuous partial derivatives and always satisfies
$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0$$
Prove $z=f(x,y)$ is constant.
To be honest I don't quite know where to start. I tried rewriting the equation as a matrix multiplication
$$[x,y](\nabla f(x,y))=0$$
but this seems to be of little or no help.
Can anyone help me on this or give some hint that may push me further? Best regards!

Comment: Take derivative with respect to $t$ of $g(t)=f(tx,ty)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $g(t)=f(tx,ty)$. Then

> $$tg'(t)=tf(tx,ty)'=txf_x(tx,ty)+tyf_y(tx,ty)=0$$
>  Therefore $g'(t)=0$, $t\neq0$, and by continuity also at $t=0$.
>
>  Hence $f(x,y)=g(1)=g(0)=f(0,0)$.